# SQL division giving wrong answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, divide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is wrong with this SQL Server query division calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112462/what-is-wrong-with-this-sql-server-query-division-calculation)

I am dividing two values in SQL like

```
SELECT SUM(totalCalls), 
    SUM(EnteredBTN), 
    SUM(EnteredBTN) * 100 / SUM(totalCalls),
    SUM(EnteredACC), 
    SUM(EnteredACC) / SUM(totalCalls), 
    SUM(SentToTrans),
    SUM(SentToTrans) * 100 / SUM(totalCalls),
    SUM(Complete_Information), 
    SUM(Complete_Information) * 100 / SUM(SentToTrans)
```

Now when I do `SUM(EnteredACC)/SUM(totalCalls)` i.e **7/48**, it should give me **.14** but it gives **0** instead.

When I do `SUM(EnteredACC)*100/SUM(totalCalls)` it should give **14.58** (or **15** when rounded off) but it gives **14** as the result. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You're dividing an integer by an integer. This results in an integer. If you want a decimal result, try `*100.0` or `*1.0`. If you want to specify number of decimal places, use an explicit cast like Lamak's and Void Ray's answers - but please specify an explicit precision + scale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simple, most likely the data type of the columns `EnteredACC` and `totalCalls` is `INT` (or `SMALLINT`, `BIGINT`,etc), therefore it your result is an `INT`. So, 14.58 becomes 14 and 0.14 becomes 0. You need to do a cast (implicit or explicit) to your datatype:

```
SUM(CAST(EnteredACC AS DECIMAL(16,4))/SUM(totalCalls)
```

Comment: Thanks i had everything set to decimal type except for this particular temporary table . I missed it somehow thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0):

Try: `select cast(cast(7 as decimal(18,2))/cast(48 as decimal(18,2)) as decimal(18,2))`

Comment: If you're going to explicitly cast as decimal, you should include precision and scale. Do you know what the defaults are? Does the OP? Will future readers?

Comment: I was just trying to point out that the issue is with the data type. Precision and scale are not in question here.

Comment: It is still poor practice to ever - especially when demonstrating code - exclude precision/scale/length. Here are my arguments about VARCHAR but they apply equally to DECIMAL, VARBINARY, DATETIME2, etc.: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Aaron, I would have to agree re: Varchar, but for decimal and especially for some demo code, defaults are just fine; IMHO.

Comment: you're missing my point. And that's okay, hopefully other readers will get it.

Comment: well, I can say the same; let's leave it at that...

Answer (score 0):

You need floating point division, not integer division.

```
SELECT SUM(totalCalls), 
    SUM(EnteredBTN), 
    SUM(EnteredBTN)*100/CAST(SUM(totalCalls) as FLOAT),
    SUM(EnteredACC), 
    SUM(EnteredACC)/SUM(totalCalls), 
    SUM(SentToTrans),
    SUM(SentToTrans) * 100 / SUM(totalCalls),
    SUM(Complete_Information), 
    SUM(Complete_Information) * 100 / CAST(SUM(SentToTrans) as FLOAT)
```

Comment: I disagree that FLOAT is the right answer here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `decimal` more appropriate?

Comment: Because the OP only seems to want two decimal places. Why would FLOAT be better, aside from the fact that you will end up with much bigger numbers to look at such as `14.58000000000000000001`?

Comment: Ahh gotcha. So it is not a matter of performance, but a matter of style? I only have about a year of SQL experience, so I didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: Well, and accuracy, too. You should only use FLOAT, IMHO, if you specifically want its approximation properties. In *most* business applications (I would never say *all*), FLOAT is not warranted. I've been using SQL Server since 6.5 and I have yet to deal directly with any customer system where FLOAT was the better choice. I'm sure they exist, but when we're talking about dividing integers and expressing percentages, FLOAT is not the right choice. Again, IMHO.