# % change between 2 columns values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get % change between 2 columns values in table. I am bit confused as to why % change is always returned as 0.

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE Host  
(
    HostName Varchar(100),
    tcCount int,
    PrCount int
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO Host (HostName, tcCount, prCount) 
VALUES ('AppServer04', 125, 5852);
INSERT INTO Host (HostName, tcCount, prCount) 
VALUES ('AppServer05', 300 , 4318);

-- fetch 
SELECT
    HostName, tcCount, PrCount,
    (prCount - tcCount) / prCount * 100 AS 'Change(%)' 
FROM 
    Host
```

Result I am getting of above is below:

```
HostName                                          tcCount     PrCount     Change(%)  
---------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
AppServer04                                         125        5852           0
AppServer05                                         300        4318           0

(2 rows affected)
```

For AppServer04 % change should be 97.86 while AppServer05 should be 93.05. I am bit confused as to why I get 0 for both rows..

Am I missing anything here??

Comment: Try * 100.0   Note the decimal    An INT divided by an INT will return an INT.   Also, you may want to trap the dreaded Divide By Zero via  nullif( yourdenom ,0 )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL division giving wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163395/sql-division-giving-wrong-answer) AND [What is wrong with this SQL Server query division calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112462/what-is-wrong-with-this-sql-server-query-division-calculation)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti *100 doesnt work as suggested below op. Issue is data type conversion. I will add NULLIF to avoid divide by zero issue. thanks for your help.

Comment: @ZulfiqarDholkawala  100.0   (point zero)   this will give you an implicit conversion to a float  take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/bYyZnvTe

Answer (score 1):

It's a type thing. Try this:

```
SELECT
    HostName, tcCount, PrCount,
    CONVERT(decimal, prCount - tcCount) / prCount * 100 AS 'Change(%)' 
FROM 
    Host
```

If `prCount = 5852` and `tcCount = 125` then subtracting one from the other gives `5727`. `5727/5852` is `0.978639`, however SQL Server is thinking this should be an integer so is truncating it at the decimal point to give `0`. `0 * 100` is also `0`. By converting the first part of the calculation to a decimal it causes the rest of to be done using decimals as well hence the `0.978639` isn't truncated.